# How to preserve selection in UITableView Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a fairly simple app with a few UIViewControllers some of which have UITableViews added.

(Note: I am not using UITableViewControllers!)

My goal is to keep the selected row highlighted (selected) when scrolling the table and when moving to a different view then back.

Example 1:
View A with Table A - select row 3
Scroll the table up/down - row 3 should remain selected.

Example 2:
View A with Table A - select row 2
Segue to View B with Table B, select nothing, segue back to View A.
Row two should (still) be selected.

The way it is now, the selected row becomes deselected when I scroll or move to another view controller (and back).

Any ideas why I can't retain the selected row ?

EDIT:

I found that the issue is this line of code:

```
tableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .middle)
```

However if I change ".middle" to ".none" it works as expected:

```
tableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
```

Of course now I can't bring the selected row into view.

Any ideas on why this happens or how to resolve it?

Comment: If you were using a UITableViewController, your case 2 would happen automatically. Since you are not, it is your job to "memorize" the selected row on `viewWillDisappear` and restore it on `viewWillAppear`. — As for case 1, you know when the table view scrolls and when it stops scrolling (by acting as the scroll view delegate) so you are free to select whatever you like at that point.

Comment: @matt - I've done the "memorizing" bit but as shown in my EDIT found that `selectRow` doesn't stay highlighted unless i use `.none` - Any ideas for that?